# Ошибка кода для резервного копирования из книги A Byte of Python

Tags: python, архивация

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать , собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\Code']

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'D:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь,который вы будете использовать

# 3. Файлы помещаются в Zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешна создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Мой вопрос: тут все в точности как в книге, но все рано выводит:

> Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ

Как решить проблему?

Comment: У вас в системе установлена консольная утилита zip?

Comment: Уже не первый вопрос с этой проблемой с таким кодом из той книги...

Comment: А `'C:\Code'` - слеш экранировать не надо?

Answer (score 3):

Причина: на ПК не установлена программа **zip**, или путь к ней не прописан в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Возьмите ее [отсюда](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm) и установите.

Перед запуском .py установите:

```
set "PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;%PATH%"
```